# How to Get Coordination of each point when we draw something in drawing area?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, image-processing, webpack

I'm setting up git-hub opensource project for drawing some shapes and do some calculations with that. There is two main categories call 2D Sketcher and 3D sketcher. I'm using 2D sketcher. Now I need to know how to get "X" and "Y" coordination of any drawing point, in to specific variable ?

2D sketcher project can run using below link

http://web-cad.org/sketcher.html

Full project link : https://github.com/xibyte/jsketcher

I need to edit 2D sketcher code. 
2D Sketcher path : jsketcher-master > web > sketcher.html

I referred codes files a lot of times. but i didn't find where those design/ drowning methods located in this project. Because there is lot of code lines in one file.

To run this 2d Sketcher project, first we need to create a folder called "static" in web folder. Then we need to put "sketcher.bundle.js" file in to it. Then open "sketcher.html" file using google chrome.

need to use chrome web browser to run properly.

Full project link : https://github.com/xibyte/jsketcher

Comment: So you want us to search that repository for the code that handles coordinates while drawing? Do you want to do something similar like the project linked? I don't quite understand what your goal is here.

Comment: For now I need to know the code that handles coordinates while drawing.

Comment: No, I already have that repository. I need to get that drawing coordination. For that first i have to find it. then i can try to use that coordinates for my work.